# High School Math Help Word Problem Precalculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The frequency of a sound wave is called its pitch. The pitch *p* of a musical tone and its wavelength *w* are related by the equation p=v/w, where *v* is the velocity of sound through air. Suppose a sound wave has a velocity of 1056 feet/second.

a.) Graph the equation p=v/w. What lines are close to the maximum values for the pitch and the wavelength?

b.) What happens to the pitch of the tone as the wavelength decreases?

c.) If the wavelength is doubled, what happens to the pitch of the tone?

Would the equation I put into the calculator be y=1056/x? Sorry, I am confused with this question because there line seems to be getting closer to zero, but I don't think that would really make sense because I dont think the pitch, wavelength, or velocity should be decreasing? If anyone could help me answer these questions, that would be very much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are putting the right equation into the calculator. The line getting close to the $x$-axis means that when the wavelength is very long (large $x$), the pitch is very close to zero (small $y$). It’s not a question of something decreasing, at least not if you mean by that something happening as time passes, because neither of the coordinates represents time. (Often, you will graph something and the $x$ direction will be time, but not here.)

Comment: @SteveKass But then what lines would be close to the maximum value for pitch and wavelength as there is not an exact maximum?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what part a) is asking, because there is no maximum possible pitch or maximum wavelength. There are minimums ($0$ in both cases, which are represented by the coordinate axes).

Comment: @SteveKass I'm confused with that too. Thank you for the help though!